# Trying to use a For Loop to grab multiple files from a File Upload Control to attach the files to email

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

What is happening here is that I can loop and get the files.  The problem is say that I have 2 files that I have generated from the asp.net/jquery multiple upload control it grabs the first attachment 3 times and then the second attachment is not viewable.  So the files are generated twice into the attachment area in outlook.  Here is my code:

```
        HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
            string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName);
            Attachment attachFile = new Attachment(multipleFile.PostedFile.InputStream,      strFileName);
            mailmessage.Attachments.Add(attachFile);

                //uploadfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Photos/") + strFileName);
                mailmessage.Attachments.Add(attachFile);
                lblMessage.Text += strFileName + "   " + "Saved Successfully<br>";

        }
```

I do not understand what is happening with my For Loop but to me it looks like it should work.

Comment: looks like you should be using a property of `uploadFile` rather than `multipleFile.PostedFile.InputStream` to get each file contents in turn (I imagine that stream is going to contain ALL of the uploaded files - not just the one you are interested in) - but I'm going to have to go check to see whether I'm making a fool of myself...

Comment: My code is not going to help you - as I'm posting each file, one at a time and using `HttpPostedFileBase` in my controller to write the contents to disk.  It does look like `multipleFile.PostedFile.InputStream` contains all of the files - so you need to figure out how to split that stream at the divider for each uploaded file.

Comment: There is a FileUpload.PostedFiles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfiles(v=vs.110).aspx which returns System.Collections.Generic.IList<HttpPostedFile> - which may give you what you want (if you are using .NET Framework 4.5)

Comment: I am trying to grab multiple files to add to an attachment to an email.  I am using .Net Framework 4.0.  My For Loop works in a way but like I said it is grabbing the first file 3 times and the second file once but the file is corrupted.

Comment: Ok, so I used the uploadfile and I'm getting better results but now it's duplicating every file.  What can I do so it doesn't duplicate the files?

Comment: you are calling `mailmessage.Attachments.Add(attachFile);` twice in your code

Answer (score 2):

use the stream on the `uploadfile` object - and remove one of the calls to `mailmessage.Attachments.Add()` :-

```
HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
    string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName);
    Attachment attachFile = new Attachment(uploadfile.InputStream, strFileName);

    //uploadfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Photos/") + strFileName);
    mailmessage.Attachments.Add(attachFile);
    lblMessage.Text += strFileName + "   " + "Saved Successfully<br>";
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.  It's always a good idea to "accept" (tick mark) an answer that fixes your problem - so other users don't spend time addressing an issue that has already been fixed.